# How can I transfer my Bitcoins from Coin Cafe to my local MultiBit wallet?

Tags: withdrawal

I recently purchased a fair sum of bitcoins through Coin Cafe. My transaction went through without a hitch and my coins are sitting in an online wallet given to me through their site. I chose MultiBit as my desktop wallet and I set it up earlier today to have myself ready for coin transfer once my coins were available.

How can I transfer my bitcoins from Coin Cafe to my MultiBit wallet?

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what problem you are having. What have you done? What are you expecting to happen? All you have said is that you have waited four hours for something, but you haven't said what.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear what you have tried so far, but step-by-step you want to do something along the lines of this:

1. In **Multibit** create a new receiving address by clicking the "New" button.
2. On **Coin Cafe** look for a "Send Bitcoins" or "Withdraw Bitcoins" option.
3. Check out any help provided on this option, to see if there is a fee for the withdrawal.
4. The "Withdrawal option" should allow you to specify a destination and an amount: Put the "receiving address" you created in Multibit as destination, and (if there is a fee for the withdrawal) `your balance - fee` as the amount.
5. Confirm the transaction/withdrawal

If you cannot find a withdrawal option, check out the help section, or get in touch with Coin Cafe's customer service: They provide a live chat, service email address and phone number.